# Dropping duplicate strings when using group_concat in Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, merge, sqlite, virtual-layer, concatenation

When using Virtual Layer to `group_concat()` a string field, the result would contain duplicates `string`. For example, here's a polygon layer `"city_lot"` with `"land_use"` and `"owner"` fields.

[image]

I want to create a virtual layer that merges lots by owner. So here's the query:

```sql
select st_union(geometry),"owner",
    group_concat("land_use") as 'land_use',
    group_concat("fid") as 'fid'
from "city_lot" 
group by "owner"
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Notice that the 3rd record has two `"residence"` in the `"land_use"` field. My question is, instead of being `"residence,commerce,residence"`, would that be possible to make the result be `"residence,commerce"`, merging identical `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the desired output, use the [`DISTINCT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement inside of `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, i.e. `group_concat(DISTINCT "land_use") as 'land_use'`.

Here is a small example.

Let's assume there is a vector layer with the following attribute table

[image: input]

So, now with this query:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("Quality") AS "Quality_Agg", "Quantity"
FROM "random_points_test"
GROUP BY "Quantity"
```

I will aggregate values from a field `"Quality"` based on `"Quantity"` values

[image: result_1]

To get unique values i.e. **drop duplicate values**, nest `DISTINCT` into your query

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "Quality") AS "Quality_Agg", "Quantity"
FROM "random_points_test"
GROUP BY "Quantity"
```

Now the result will look like this

[image: result_2]

Mind that `DISTINCT` statement can be used multiple times, e.g.

```sql
SELECT "Quantity",
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "Quality") AS "Quality_Agg",
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "Info") AS "Info_Agg"
FROM "random_points_test"
GROUP BY "Quantity"
```

---

**References:**

- [MariaDB Server Documentation | GROUP_CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/)
- [MySQL DISTINCT on a GROUP_CONCAT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083499/mysql-distinct-on-a-group-concat)
- [MySQL Tutorial | Introduction to MySQL DISTINCT clause](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)
- [MySQL – GROUP_CONCAT unique values](http://www.it-iss.com/mysql/mysql-group_concat-unique-values/)